# How to pass the output of a subprocess to the input of another subprocess?

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I have some bash commands that process a csv file for a project, and I'm trying to transform them into a Python script. The problem is that I want to pass the output of a subprocess as the input of a new one, without having to create an extra file. The code below extracts the 12th field out of a csv file, which contains links I want to process with the second command:

```
import sys
import getopt
import subprocess
import shlex

def main(argv):
    inputfile=''
    try:
        opts,args=getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:",["ifile="])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print('The correct format is Script.py -i <result csv file>')
        sys.exit(2)
    
    for opt,arg in opts:
        if opt == '-h':
            print('Script.py -i <input csv file>')
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
            inputfile=arg
    
    print('Input file is ',inputfile)

    def run_prog(prog):
            p1 = subprocess.Popen(prog, shell=True, stdin=open(inputfile,'r'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
            print(p1.stdout.read())
            second_command = 'for var in $(cat '+p1.stdout.read()+'); do echo ${var%/*}; done'
            p2 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(second_command), stdin=p1.stdout, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
            print(p2.stdout.read())
    
    def brokenlinks():
        cmd=r"""awk -F "," '{print $12}'"""
        run_prog(cmd)
    brokenlinks()

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

How would I go about redirecting the output of p1 to p2 in order to run the second command? The code I get now throws me a "var was unexpected at this time." when printing p2.stdout.read().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually fetching `p1.stdout` twice during your second command: first during the command itself (which is a bad idea because it could be exploited to inject code, among other issues) and then during the stdin of p2.

I would suggest to eliminate the first fetch and simply rely on the fact that you are passing the pipe of p1.stdout to p2.stdin.

```py
def run_prog(prog):
        p1 = subprocess.Popen(prog, shell=True, stdin=open(inputfile,'r'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
        print(p1.stdout.read())
        second_command = 'while read var; do echo ${var%/*}; done'
        p2 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(second_command), stdin=p1.stdout, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
        print(p2.stdout.read())
```

The only difference here is the definition of `second_command` which reads each line using `while` instead of looping using `for`.

There are many ways to do the same operation without relying on a `for` nor a `while` loop. Since you need to remove the characters after the last slash, including the slash itself, you could use sed:

```
        second_command = "sed 's,/[^/]*$,,'"
```

Of course you could also perform all of these operations in pure Python, but I assume this is not why you came here for in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! It worked with sed once I eliminated the first fetch and set the shell = False in p2.